# How to update a record's detail

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I am using some Hiberanate and JSP with my project. In first request I get the userID and  phone number of the user. That time, I should save the that user's detail in a table which is having 5 columns. That table, only the USER_ID and the PHONE_NO fields should be saved. Then the second request carries the detail to fill other three fields (columns).
At first time I can save the data into mysql server but I don't know how to update the same record.  Someone had posted I have to write a query. Is that correct or is there a special way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about how use the Hibernate framework. I recommend do a Google search and follow some tutorials. Like this: http://www.javabeat.net/difference-between-hibernates-saveupdate-and-saveorupdate-methods/

If you still have problems to do this update, you can copy and paste your code here, then the people can help you.